# First scanf("%s") breaks when second scanf("%s") is used, reading 0

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

I'm making a very simple BFS search for Traveling Knight problem. Unfortunately, my input decides to go awry. This piece of code gives a correct result.

```
char start[2], destination[2];
scanf("%s", start);                    // input string is "e2"
printf("%d %d\n", start[0], start[1]); // start[0] = 101, start[1] = 50 
                                          (in ASCII, 101 is 'e' and 50 is '2')
```

The one I use

```
scanf("%s", start);                    // input string is "e2"
scanf("%s", destination);              // input string is "e4"
printf("%d %d\n", start[0], start[1]); // start[0] = 0, start[1] = 50
```

or

```
scanf("%s %s", start, destination);    // input string is "e2 e4"
printf("%d %d\n", start[0], start[1]); // start[0] = 0, start[1] = 50
```

the destination array doesn't suffer this kind of error though. Did i do something wrong? If this is a mistake, is there an alternative that I can use?

EDIT: Start is declared as char[2], likewise with destination. SSCCE

```
void main()
{
    char start[2], destination[2];
    scanf("%s", start);                    // input string is "e2"
    scanf("%s", destination);              // input string is "e4"
    printf("%d %d\n", start[0], start[1]); // start[0] = 101, start[1] = 50 
}
```

Comment: Show the declarations of the variables `start`  and `destination` please (*update the question; not here in a comment*). Or better still, a full-on [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). My crystal ball tells me `start` is declared `char start[2];`, likewise with `destination`.

Comment: I hope you've allocated space for "start[]" and "destination[]".  For example: `char start[80], destination[80];`.

Comment: @WhozCraig, you're right, it is.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I call witch! Burn her!!

Comment: @KlemensSoargo: in case it's not clear from @WhozCraig's comment, your `start` and `destination` arrays aren't large enough because there needs to be room for the string's terminating null in addition to the characters in the string.

Comment: Oh, I never thought of that. I'll try it now.

Comment: Problem solved! Need to add more space for terminating null. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four things.

1. `void main()` isn't standard. It should return an `int`
2. Your char buffers aren't big enough.
3. Length-limit any strings you `scanf()` to arrays to be one-less than the array size. That right there would have hinted to you your buffers were too small. `"%1s"` Hmm....
4. Validate your `scanf()` results before relying on them.

That said,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int res = EXIT_FAILURE;

    char start[3], destination[3];
    if (scanf("%2s", start) == 1 && 
        scanf("%2s", destination) == 1)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", start[0], start[1]);
        res = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    return res;
}
```